# Organizing Python code in modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, circular-dependency, code-organization

I am exploring organizing Python applications into different structures and the one that seems most natural to me does not work because of what looks like a circular dependency.  The goal of the organization is to move classes into their own files and let modules be controlled by their own `__init__.py`.

Anyway on to the code. I have an app with this structure

```
/app
  |__ user
  |    |__ __init__.py
  |    |__ user_dao
  |    |__ user_dto
  |    |__ user_record
  |
  |_app.py
```

after that the `/app/user/__init__.py` looks something like this.

```
from user_dao import UserDAO
from user_dto import UserDTO
from user_record import UserRecord
```

and the all the user objects depend on each other in liniar object graph `UserDTO -> UserDAO -> UserRecord` where `->` is equivalent to "depends on".

And finally in `app.py` there is something similar to

```
from user import UserDAO
from user import UserDTO
```

When the app tries to run I get the error

```
ImportError UserDAO
```

with a stack trace that points to a circular dependency.  Is there a better way to organize similar code in Python besides putting all classes in the same file so the modules work.

Any suggestions about application design in python are helpful, and thank you.

Comment: shouldn't it be `from user.userdao import UserDao`?

Comment: I tried this code and it is ok for me, no ImportError. I use python 2.6.6

Comment: Also tested on windows with python 2.7.3, without error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error depends on how exactly the `user_*.py` files are written: if they say `from user import UserDAO` as well, then they depend circularly on the code in `__init__.py` having finished to execute.  To avoid that, they should say `from user.user_dao import UserDAO` explicitly.